# "get in using" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "Exactly," said Harry. "And we know you **get in using** those funny coins, or tokens, or whatever they are, because I saw that witch borrowing one from here friend -"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I looked up "[get in](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+in)", but it seems to me that none of definitions could fit for the context. If I have to guess, I think it probably means ***to succeed in doing something***. However, I don't know if I'm getting it right. Is it a common usage? What does it truly mean?

Comment: It is not clear from the given context is. Why can it not be the simple meaning (i.e., getting in to a secret club or place by giving tokens/coins at the door)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence in the question, *get in* is not a set phrase (or phrasal verb). It is simply two words put next to each other.

If looking it up in a dictionary, you would look up the verb *get* and the preposition *in*.

In this case, *in* means the same thing as *inside*, so the sentence could be paraphrased:

> "And we know you get inside [the room/place] using those funny coins …"

---

The above sense of *in* should not be confused with the more colloquial *the **in** crowd*,  *you should **get into** the movie*, or *I'm **in on** the bet*, none of which uses *in* as a preposition of physical location, but instead as a figurative expression of joining or being aware of something.

Unfortunately, knowing the difference in cases like this is often a matter of familiarity, use, and context, rather than something that can be quickly determined by looking it up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To "get in" means to successfully enter.  Then "... using those funny coins" is a participle phrase describing how to get in

> You can get in through the back door, which is unlocked.
>
> You get in most houses using a key.